# How to update specific row in datecolumn to date today after update on other column using after update trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date, triggers, sql-update

How to update date Column **DateMod** to today's date when Column **CustomerProductID** is updated (not inserted) using an after update trigger in T-SQL?

Some background info: Table already contains list of products (key column **Itemcode**), once the CustomerProductID is received it changes the column for that particular row (product) from NULL to integer value. This update is the trigger to update column DateMod to todays date for the row (product). 
I am using SSMS 2008 and have something like the following code which changes the whole date column, not the particular date field for the updated row:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
   ON Table1
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      IF UPDATE (CustomerProductID) BEGIN
        Update Table1
        SET DateMod=GETDATE() 
      END
END
```

I have read some solutions using old.value and new.value or using where exists (select from inserted/updated), but how does that work? If both methods work, which one is the most beneficial in this case?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer do this as a `before update` trigger (a logical thing . . . doing updates in after update triggers suggests infinite loops and is not allowed in some databases).  But SQL Server doesn't support that.

In any case, the right syntax is to use `inserted` to join back to the original table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
   ON Table1
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      IF UPDATE(CustomerProductID) BEGIN
        Update t1
            SET DateMod = GETDATE() 
            FROM Table1 t1 join
                 Inserted i
                 ON Table1.PrimaryKeyColumn = i.PrimaryKeyColumn
      END
END
```

Change the code so `PrimaryKeyColumn` is the right primary key column.

Comment: Thanks! Just wondering: so sql has a (temporary) tabel for Inserted I guess, does it also have a table Updated?

Comment: @J3FFK . . . There is a view called `inserted` and `deleted`, which can be used in triggers.  Updates use both.  These apparently are implemented as views on the log, so they cannot be modified directly.

Comment: Just tried implementing but MSSQL seems to support only instead or after updates (not before).

Comment: @J3FFK . . . That "triggers" my memory about this.  Instead there is this complicated system to prevent triggers from cascading indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried using After update, which works. Fortunately, the CustomerProductID can only be updated once and it is stored in just one table so cascading won't be a problem I think.